# Science proof for a claim of an author regarding concentration?

Tags: concentration, multi-tasking

In his book Cal Newport, mentions:

> To make matters worse for depth, there’s
> increasing evidence that this shift toward the shallow is not a choice that can be easily
> reversed. Spend enough time in a state of frenetic shallowness and you permanently
> reduce your capacity to perform deep work.

What is the evidence/proof that shallownes or multitasking cause permanent reduction in the capacity to concentrate?

He doesn't cite them in the book...

Comment: Welcome Chicago. We're expected to show our background research into answering questions here, also to phrase questions within the field the site covers. Can you also define the terms you're using, what does "shallow" mean in the context of the quote and in terms of psychology or neuroscience, could you cite a source.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am referring to Cal Newport's book "Deep work": 
ISBN-10 ‏ : ‎ 1455586692
ISBN-13 ‏ : ‎ 978-1455586691

I guess that's the problem itself, I dont exactly know what the author refers to, but he seems to infer that multitasking can permanently reduce your concentration ability; but he cites no sources...

Comment: Your question should include the citation, not just a comment. At a bare minimum, you need to include the title of a book when you refer to it, otherwise who knows which book you mean? I also think there needs to be a bit more context, as out of context it's unclear what the author is talking about at all - you shouldn't expect that anyone here is familiar with this book. In any event, the self-help genre is generally junk - the vast majority of the words written there are not referenced or based on any science. If this is the only such statement in this book, then that's quite impressive.